# Spark and Java: Exception thrown in awaitResult

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hdfs, protocol-buffers

I am trying to connect a Spark cluster running within a virtual machine with IP `10.20.30.50` and port `7077` from within a Java application and run the word count example:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://10.20.30.50:7077").setAppName("wordCount");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaRDD<String> textFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:8020/README.md");
String result = Long.toString(textFile.count());
JavaRDD<String> words = textFile.flatMap((FlatMapFunction<String, String>) s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")).iterator());
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pairs = words.mapToPair((PairFunction<String, String, Integer>) s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1));
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = pairs.reduceByKey((Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>) (a, b) -> a + b);
counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:8020/tmp/output");
sc.stop();
return result;
```

The Java application shows the following stack trace:

```
Running Spark version 2.0.1
Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Changing view acls to: lii5ka
Changing modify acls to: lii5ka
Changing view acls groups to:
Changing modify acls groups to:
SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(lii5ka); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(lii5ka); groups with modify permissions: Set()
Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 61267.
Registering MapOutputTracker
Registering BlockManagerMaster
Created local directory at /private/var/folders/4k/h0sl02993_99bzt0dzv759000000gn/T/blockmgr-51de868d-3ba7-40be-8c53-f881f97ced63
MemoryStore started with capacity 2004.6 MB
Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
Logging initialized @48403ms
jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1316e7ec{/jobs,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@782de006{/jobs/json,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2d0353{/jobs/job,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@381e24a0{/jobs/job/json,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1c138dc8{/stages,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@b29739c{/stages/json,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@63f6de31{/stages/stage,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2a04ddcb{/stages/stage/json,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2af9688e{/stages/pool,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6a0c5bde{/stages/pool/json,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3f5e17f8{/storage,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@33b86f5d{/storage/json,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5264dcbc{/storage/rdd,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5a3ebf85{/storage/rdd/json,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@159082ed{/environment,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6522c585{/environment/json,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@115774a1{/executors,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3e3a3399{/executors/json,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2f2c5959{/executors/threadDump,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5c51afd4{/executors/threadDump/json,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@76893a83{/static,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@19c07930{/,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@54eb0dc0{/api,null,AVAILABLE}
Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5953786{/stages/stage/kill,null,AVAILABLE}
Started ServerConnector@2eeb8bd6{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4040}
Started @48698ms
Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.0.104:4040
Connecting to master spark://10.20.30.50:7077...
Successfully created connection to /10.20.30.50:7077 after 25 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
Connecting to master spark://10.20.30.50:7077...
Still have 2 requests outstanding when connection from /10.20.30.50:7077 is closed
Failed to connect to master 10.20.30.50:7077

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167) ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:88) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:96) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:106) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection from /10.20.30.50:7077 closed
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelInactive(TransportResponseHandler.java:128) ~[spark-network-common_2.11-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelInactive(TransportChannelHandler.java:109) ~[spark-network-common_2.11-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:208) ~[netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:4.0.29.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:194) ~[netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:4.0.29.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75) ~[netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:4.0.29.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelInactive(IdleStateHandler.java:257) ~[netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:4.0.29.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:208) ~[netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:4.0.29.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:194) ~[netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:4.0.29.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75) ~[netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:4.0.29.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:208) ~[netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:4.0.29.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:194) ~[netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:4.0.29.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75) ~[netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:4.0.29.Final]
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelInactive(TransportFrameDecoder.java:182) ~[spark-network-common_2.11-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:208) ~[netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:4.0.29.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:194) ~[netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:4.0.29.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:828) ~[netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:4.0.29.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:621) ~[netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:4.0.29.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357) ~[netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:4.0.29.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357) ~[netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:4.0.29.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111) ~[netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:4.0.29.Final]
        ... 1 common frames omitted
```

In the Spark Master log on `10.20.30.50`, I get the following error message:

```
16/11/05 14:47:20 ERROR OneForOneStrategy: Error while decoding incoming Akka PDU of length: 1298
akka.remote.transport.AkkaProtocolException: Error while decoding incoming Akka PDU of length: 1298
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.PduCodecException: Decoding PDU failed.
    at akka.remote.transport.AkkaPduProtobufCodec$.decodePdu(AkkaPduCodec.scala:167)
    at akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor.akka$remote$transport$ProtocolStateActor$$decodePdu(AkkaProtocolTransport.scala:580)
    at akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor$$anonfun$4.applyOrElse(AkkaProtocolTransport.scala:375)
    at akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor$$anonfun$4.applyOrElse(AkkaProtocolTransport.scala:343)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at akka.actor.FSM$class.processEvent(FSM.scala:604)
    at akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor.processEvent(AkkaProtocolTransport.scala:269)
    at akka.actor.FSM$class.akka$actor$FSM$$processMsg(FSM.scala:598)
    at akka.actor.FSM$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(FSM.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
    at akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor.aroundReceive(AkkaProtocolTransport.scala:269)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:89)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readTag(CodedInputStream.java:108)
    at akka.remote.WireFormats$AkkaProtocolMessage.<init>(WireFormats.java:6643)
    at akka.remote.WireFormats$AkkaProtocolMessage.<init>(WireFormats.java:6607)
    at akka.remote.WireFormats$AkkaProtocolMessage$1.parsePartialFrom(WireFormats.java:6703)
    at akka.remote.WireFormats$AkkaProtocolMessage$1.parsePartialFrom(WireFormats.java:6698)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:141)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:176)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:188)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:193)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    at akka.remote.WireFormats$AkkaProtocolMessage.parseFrom(WireFormats.java:6821)
    at akka.remote.transport.AkkaPduProtobufCodec$.decodePdu(AkkaPduCodec.scala:168)
    ... 19 more
```

**Additional Information**

- The example works fine when I use `new SparkConf().setMaster("local")` instead
- I can connect to the Spark Master with `spark-shell --master spark://10.20.30.50:7077` on the very same machine

Comment: You cannot connect to the node on local machine with this ip `10.20.30.50:7077`

Comment: why not? Spark is running in a virtual machine on my host that is accessible via this IP - so I don't see why I shouldn't be able to connect to it? Is this any special restriction in Spark?

Comment: You never told me that there is a virtual machine in between

Comment: BTW see if the IP is reachable from outside the virtual machine

Comment: I edited my question and yes - the machine is reachable (this should be clear by getting an entry in the logfile within the Spark master on the VM). The Java log also states `Successfully created connection to /10.20.30.50:7077` which means that a connection was successful.

Comment: Connection got closed for some reason ..check the code why

Comment: A guess: your Spark master (on `10.20.30.50:7077`) runs a different Spark version (perhaps 1.6?): your driver code uses Spark 2.0.1, which (I _think_) doesn't even use Akka, and the message on the master says something about failing to decode Akka protocol - can you check the version used on master?

Comment: @MichaelLihs: pls check my answer. it might help to resolve.Danken!

Comment: @TzachZohar:  "which (I think) doesn't even use Akka, " pls see https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-akka-netty.html

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: Can you pls throw some light on this.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, will further dig into that tomorrow, I'm on the road at the moment... guess it's a version mismatch...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> *Looks like network error in the first place (but actually NOT) in the disguise of version mismatch of spark . You can point to correct
>   version of spark jars mostly assembly jars.*

This issue may happen due to version miss match in Hadoop RPC call using Protobuffer.

[when a protocol message being parsed is invalid in some way, e.g. it contains a malformed varint or a negative byte length.](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.4.1/akka/protobuf/InvalidProtocolBufferException.html)

- My experience with protobuf, `InvalidProtocolBufferException` can happen, only  when the message was not able to parse(programatically if you are parsing protobuf message, may be message legth is zero or message is corrupted...).
- Spark uses Akka Actors for Message Passing between Master/Driver and Workers and [Internally akka uses googles protobuf to communicate. see method below from AkkaPduCodec.scala)](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/akka-2.3/akka-remote/src/main/scala/akka/remote/transport/AkkaPduCodec.scala.shtml)

  ```
  override def decodePdu(raw: ByteString): AkkaPdu = {
      try {
        val pdu = AkkaProtocolMessage.parseFrom(raw.toArray)
        if (pdu.hasPayload) Payload(ByteString(pdu.getPayload.asReadOnlyByteBuffer()))
        else if (pdu.hasInstruction) decodeControlPdu(pdu.getInstruction)
        else throw new PduCodecException("Error decoding Akka PDU: Neither message nor control message were contained", null)
      } catch {
        case e: InvalidProtocolBufferException â‡’ throw new PduCodecException("Decoding PDU failed.", e)
      }
    }
  ```

But in your case, since its version mismatch, new protobuf version message cant be parsed from old version of parser... or something like...

If you are using maven other dependencies, pls. review.

Comment: For me it was the scala version (patch). Thanks!

Comment: @combinatorist, am also facing issue with spark-java , how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that I had Spark version 1.5.2 running in the virtual machine and used version 2.0.1 of the Spark library in Java. I fixed the issue by using the appropriate Spark library version in my `pom.xml` which is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Another problem (that occurred later) was, that I also had to pin the Scala version with which the library was build. This is the `_2.10` suffix in the artifactId.

Basically @RamPrassad's answer pointed me into the right direction but didn't give a clear advice what I need to do to fix my problem.

By the way: I couldn't update Spark in the virtual machine, since it was brought to me by the HortonWorks distribution...

Comment: "If you are using maven other dependencies pls. review."... I wasn't even aware that you are using maven and suggested above in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This error also happens when you have strange characters that you wanna insert into a table, for example:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
(select 'GARDENﬠy para el uso para el control de rat쟣om﷠rata' as text)
```

So the solution is to change the encoding text or to remove these special characters like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
    (select regexp_replace('GARDENﬠy para el uso para el control de rat쟣om﷠rata', 
'[\u0100-\uffff]', '') as text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error while trying to read in data from my SQL table. My particular issue was that I did not give the SQL user sufficient permissions to read in the data.

My SQL user had permission to run a SELECT statement, but  when I look at the log via `select * from stv_recents` (on redshift) I saw that it also performs a `UNLOAD` command to s3. [Here's a resource to `GRANT` permissions on redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GRANT.html)

Not sure if this is still relevant for you seeing that this was almost 6 years ago, but I see this in your error:

> `SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(lii5ka); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(lii5ka); groups with modify permissions: Set()`

which looks like you also didn't have sufficient permissions set on your SQL user